# How to execute custom injected JavaScript before anything else with puppeteer/nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm using `puppeteer` with `nodejs`. I wanted to know if there was a (reliable) way to execute injected `JavaScript` (via `page.evaluate()`) before any other script right after navigating to a particular page.

Comment: Did you try this https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.2.1/docs/api.md#pageevaluateonnewdocumentpagefunction-args ?

Comment: @hardkoded I'll try later, thanks